# how to wait for Meteor.loggingIn() is false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I am trying to add authentication to react route. I am using Meteor and React.js.

Here is what I am doing

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/vendor/chat" component={VendorChat} onEnter={requireVendorAuth} />
</Router>
```

Here is the `requireVendorAuth` function.

```
function requireVendorAuth(nextState, replace) {
if(Meteor.loggingIn() === false) {
    const user = Meteor.user();
    let userId = user._id;
    let userProfile = user.profile.role;

    console.log(user);
    console.log(userId);
    console.log(userProfile);

    if(!userId) {
        replace({
            pathname: '/vendor/login',
            state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
        })
    } else if(userProfile !== "vendor") {
        replace({
            pathname: '/vendor/login',
            state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
        })
    }
}
}
```

I want to wait until `Meteor.loggingIn()` is false and then redirect the user.

How can I do this? Any kind of suggestion would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your function after a while block, because that will repeat when your condition is true and when it finally reaches false after however long, it ends and reaches the redirect.

```
while(Meteor.loggingIn === true) {/*Code that updates Meteor.loggingIn value when needed*/}
//Redirect here
```

I would recommend encapsualting this in an if block so that you can skip if you need to.

```
if(skip === false) {
    while(Meteor.loggingIn === true) {}
    //Redirect here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is wait for the logged state in your *startup()* method, since *loggingIn()* is a reactive variable use *Tracker.autorun()* to wait for the result:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    Tracker.autorun((computation) => {
        console.warn("Logging in...");


        if (!Meteor.loggingIn()) {
            computation.stop();
            console.warn("Initializing App...");

            render(<App />, document.getElementById("pd-root"));
        }
    });
});
```

Inside the **App** component use your regular *Router* logic, already knowing if the client is logged or not using *Meteor.user()* and redirect to your login page or logged area.